# Using named Navigator from different widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I need to navigate to a widget(screen) using named navigation from another widget(screen). This is the body of `MyHomePage` Widget

```
body: Navigator(
  key: _navigatorKey,
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    WidgetBuilder builder;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        builder = (BuildContext context) => UIHomePage();
        break;
      case '/cart':
        builder = (BuildContext context) => UICartPage();
        break;
      case '/account':
        builder = (BuildContext context) => UIAccountPage();
        break;
      default:
        throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
    }

    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings, );
  },
),
```

I can toggle these `PageRoutes` from the `bottomNavigationBar` with `_navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(routeNames[tabItem])` where `routeNames` is a list of Strings `['/', '/cart', '/account']`. This works fine.

Now, from `UIAccountPage()`, where I have a ListTile named 'Cart', I wish to navigate to the `UICartPage` on tapping that particular tile. I also have several other tiles that I wish to use to navigate to other widgets (screens).

To achieve this, do I have to expand the `onGenerateRoute` in `MyHomePage` to accommodate other routes or I have to create another custom Navigator somewhere? I am at odds. If somebody could guide with a simple illustration that would be awesome.

Thanks

**Edit:** Also I have no idea what `setting` does in Navigator and _navigatorKey is `final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>()`

Answer (score 2):

i'm pretty new using Flutter but i've this implementation an works fine for routes.

```dart
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Temp Detector',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => AuthScreen(),
        '/register': (context) => SignInScreen(),
        '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
        '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/config': (context) => ConfigScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And when i try to go to another view i use:

```dart
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
```

Where the 2nd param is the name defined in the routes.

Hope it does help you!

Comment: i do same approach as u do and i think this is the answer for him

Comment: Should I put this in a seperate class in a file and then include it where ever, I need to implement navigation. Also if there are sub level views (pages) in `/config`, say you have config -> language. At the config widget, we have to use a new navigator. Or we can expand on this existing one.

Comment: Again this will draw over the bottom navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

1, I think you should be try **BottomNavigationBar** with **PageView** or **TabView**.

2, With your issue, you can try options create a callback for **UIAccountPage**:

```
  case '/account':
    builder = (BuildContext context) => UIAccountPage(onTapCart: () {
      _navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/cart');
    });
    break;
```

And UIAccountPage

```
class UIAccountPage extends StatelessWidget {

  VoidCallback onTapCart;

  UIAccountPage({this.onTapCart});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    .....
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that navigating from those pageviews to other view paints over the bottom navigation bar